# ECB: tag file prompts?

Tags: emacs-ecb

I've been working on ECB for a small time - and suddenly ECB started to ask me which tags file to open. I've no idea what it talks about - my source codes are usually small... So I think I can be happy without those tag files. How can I turn of this tag-file prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solves the problem:

```
(setq tags-file-name (expand-file-name "~/its/dbes/etgs/TAGS"))
```

So the emacs doesn't ask about the tag file anymore.

It might be useful to tag only given set of files (for example libs). For that - remove `~/.emacs.d/semanticdb` dir, and turn off

```
(setq global-semanticdb-minor-mode nil)
```

then one should open the libs one would like to tag, and call

```
(semantic-force-refresh)
```

(default key `C-c , ,`)